# How do I convert integer to string with leading zeros in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

I'm learning Tcl. In Perl I can do this:

```
 $ perl -e 'for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { printf("name%03d\n", $i) }'
 name000
 name001
 name002
 name003
 name004
```

Can I do this in Tcl?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See [format](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/format.html):

```
$ tclsh
% for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} { puts [format "name%03d" $i] }
name000
name001
name002
name003
name004
```